# Jetty 9: Setting up handlers and connectors

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

I've looked at the documentation for Jetty 9 on the architecture (http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/architecture.html) but I am still confused about the relationship between handlers and connectors.

1. Can you link a handler to a specific connector (if so, how? The connector doesn't seem to have a setHandler method)?
2. Or does everything go to a main handler and then you distribute things from there? (i.e. You figure out form what connector it came from so then you forward it to a different handler or handle it yourself)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`Connectors` are the components that listen for incoming connections.

`Handlers` are the low level jetty mechanism used to handle *all* requests.

Jetty sends all valid requests (there are a class of requests that are just bad HTTP usage and can result in things like a `400 Bad Request`) to whatever is registered at `Server.getHandler()`

There are many types of function specific handlers, pick one that best suits your needs and extend from it, or wrap your handler around a more generalized approach.

A typical server is setup to have either a HandlerList or HandlerCollection to indicate a list of possible behavior.

Each handler is hit (in order) and if that handler decides it wants to do something it can.

If a handler actually produced something, then a call to `baseRequest.setHandled(true);` is used to tell Jetty to not process any more handlers after this current one.

As to how to restrict certain handlers to certain connectors, that's done via the virtualhosts mechanism.

VirtualHosts is a concept baked into the `ContextHandler` specific handlers, so you'll want to wrap your custom handlers in a `ContextHandler` to get the benefit of VirtualHosts.

To use this, you would name your connector using `Connector.setName(String)` and then use the `@{name}` syntax on the VirtualHosts definition of the `ContextHandler` to specific that only that named connector can be used to serve that specific `ContextHandler`.

Example:

```java
    ServerConnector httpConnector = new ServerConnector(server);
    httpConnector.setName("unsecured"); // named connector
    httpConnector.setPort(80);

    ContextHandler helloHandler = new ContextHandler();
    helloHandler.setContextPath("/hello");
    helloHandler.setHandler(new HelloHandler("Hello World"));
    helloHandler.setVirtualHosts(new String[]{"@unsecured"});
```

Comment: Wow, this is great, thank you so much. One last clarification before I mark your answer as answer, if the call to baseRequest.setHandled(true) is not made, then it will be sent to the second registered handler?

Comment: Without the `baseRequest.setHandled(true);` The request processing will just continue onto the next handler, correct.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Suppose I have a handler which sets a few header on requests and then calls `super.handle(...)`. Is it possible to mutate the `httpResponse` after `super.handle(...)` call in this handler?

Comment: @user2004685 only it that handler is an implementation of `HandlerWrapper`, and the response hasn't been committed yet.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Make sense. Thanks for explaining this.