# Bind connector to handler

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty

How to bind `Connector` to `Handler` in Jetty server?

1. Handler A -> url mapping /first -> connector open for port 8282
2. Handler B -> url mapping /second-> connector open for port 9292

So I can get result like this:

`localhost:8282/first` -> handler A will process it

`localhost:9292/second` -> handler B will process it

`localhost:8282/second` -> error 404

`localhost:9292/first` -> error 404

Right now, if I just add additional `Connector`'s for Jetty and I can access /first or /second from any port.

Answer (score 0):

Provide a `name` to the Connector, and use that `@name` in your Handler's `VirtualHost` configuration.

See prior answer (and example in it).

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26149232/775715