# Jetty: get connector used for request in servlet

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, connector

i know, that this question was asked before(long time ago...). So that's why I'm bringing it up again.

Maven pom.xml ...

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
  <version>11.0.9</version>
</dependency>
```

So this is what my Jetty "HttpServlet" looks like:

```
public class SomeServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {        

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

        response.getWriter().println("some response"));
    }
}
```

The server is implemented as follows:

```
server = new Server();

ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);

connector.setPort(8080);
connector.setHost("127.0.0.1");
connector.setName("server");

server.addConnector(connector);

ServletContextHandler handler = new ServletContextHandler();

handler.setSessionHandler(new SessionHandler());    
handler.addServlet(SomeServlet.class, "");
server.setHandler(handler);
```

Now my goal is to determine which connector was used to create the request for SomeServlet.
Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find the answer I'm looking for.

So I'm asking you for help in order to find out, if there is a way to access this information directly by using either request or response. Other solutions would be sufficient as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "determine which connector was used to create the request"? There is only one connector in your example code.

Comment: Why do you need this?  Isn't it easier to just name your connectors and use virtualhosts to ensure the requests arrive to your servlet context from the connectors you need them to?  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26148418/jetty-9-setting-up-handlers-and-connectors/26149232#26149232